# Setting topic for Skype chat

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

I made Skype links on a web page in the format: `"sip:contact.name@domain.com"`. Is there a way to set the topic of the conversation at the same time?

I tried `"sip:contact.name@domain.com?chat&topic=Topic"`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no documented option how this could be done. The reason why it isn´t really working is that Microsoft seamed to drop that. Its currently only working with emails send via Outlook:

1. Start to create an email
2. Enter an subject, which will the one you want to title your chat with
3. Enter some recipient
4. hover over the recipient and select "Send an IM to ..."

But as this is closed source its not clear how that could be used. There is also an [Feature Request](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/8741998-title-your-conversation?page=1&per_page=20) for a further version to bring exactly that feature back (as it was part from the Microsoft communicator). You might add some votes here so that it will catch the attention from Microsoft.